# Iceweasel thinks my client certificate is a server certificate; Chromium thinks it's an "other" certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, chromium

I have a client certificate from [StartCom](https://startssl.com). I recently reinstalled my OS and have to re-add the client certificate to Iceweasel in order to gain access to the control panel. I have a backup of the client certificate in PEM format.

Chromium prefers a p12 certificate, so I converted the certificate with

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -nokeys -in client.pem -out client.p12
```

However, when I add it to Chromium's certificate manager, it ends up in the "Other" category rather than the "Your certificates" category, so I can't use it to authenticate myself...

Iceweasel recognises it as a server certificate, so I can't use it there either. However, both browsers can import the file and recognise my email address in it and StartCom as the authority.

What may have happened here, and more importantly, how to recover? I know I can create a new account and request from StartCom that they merge the accounts, but it would be better to do this by myself (with your help, that is).

StartCom's root certificate is installed on my computer. Here is some relevant data about my install:

```
Chromium Version 46.0.2490.71 Built on 8.2, running on Debian 8.2 (64-bit)
Iceweasel 38.4.0
Linux zenbook 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u6 (2015-11-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You can't use it as "your" certificate if you don't have the matching private key. So when making it into a .p12, you should not have added `-nokeys`. In general, make sure your software is importing/decrypting the necessary private key.

Comment: @Spiff okay, thanks. I didn't backup the keyfile, so I'll have to create a new account and request an account merge. Then I will properly backup the new certificate with its key... Thanks!